# How to listen to music without pausing, while changing the page?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

How could i continue music playback even while changing pages using Vue js?

Principle of operation:
 1. The user starts listening to music on page `example.com`
 2. He goes to the `example.com/about` and the music he started to listen to doesn't stop.

I guess that i have to the music in the parent component as it’s own separate component, but i am not sure.

[image: Folders of the project]

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app'
  }
</script>
```

**main.js**

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import App from './App'
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
  import About from './components/About'
  import Main from './components/main'

  Vue.use(VueRouter);

  const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Main },
    { path: '/about', component: About }
  ];

  const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App },
    router
  }).$mount('#app');
```

**About.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="about">
    <h1>The about page</h1>
    <br>
    <router-link to="/">Back to main page</router-link>
    <br>
    <audio controls oncontextmenu="return false">
      <source src="../bruh.mp3">
    </audio>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'about'
  }
</script>
```

**main.vue**

```
<template>

  <div id="about">
    <h1>The main page</h1>
    <br>
    <router-link to="/about">Go to about page</router-link>
    <br>
    <audio controls oncontextmenu="return false">
      <source src="../bruh.mp3">
    </audio>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'about'
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Move the music outside of the `about.vue` page into its own component, and don't put the component within the `<router-view></router-view>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new component for the audio, and import that into your App.vue and place it outside `<router-view></router-view>`.  E.g:

**/components/AudioComponent.vue** (can't use Audio.vue because there is already an `audio` HTML element)

```
<template>
    <audio controls oncontextmenu="return false">
      <source src="../bruh.mp3">
    </audio>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // maybe take the src filename and controls on/off attribute as props?
  // maybe provide some methods for external control via an event bus or shared state
}
</script>
```

***/App.vue***

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!--  put a shared header here, e.g. links to routes, top bar, sidebar menu, etc -->
    <router-view></router-view>
    <audio-component></audio-component>
    <!-- put a shared footer here -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import AudioComponent from './components/AudioComponent.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      AudioComponent,
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am glad there are people like you. Wish you luck)